# 0 laguz transformation gauge in the beginning of battle (Path of Radiance)

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, fire-emblem-path-of-radiance

In Fire Emblem, Path of Radiance, laguz units start the battle with some fill in their transformation gauge. Still, my Lethe, who's supposed to start with full gauge, actually has zero fill:

[image]

Why?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I would experience this by equipping and then un- equipping the Demi band while at the base prior to the chapter. Can’t say for certain if that is the actual cause in your situation

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem is that Lethe starts the chapter with the demi-band, which I would like to pass to Ranulf. Is there a way to do this without transformation gauge penalty?

Comment: if there is, I can’t remember what it would be unfortunately